# Online training in convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) article the neural network is trained **online** - the input is selected during training:

> This can be done by selecting the hard
>   positive/negative exemplars from within a mini-batch.

Can someone explain online training in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online learning describes training a model one input data point at a time, or one mini-batch at a time. Typically, online learning is used because the data is coming in a stream, or because the data is too large to keep in memory all at once.

Naively training one example at a time will typically take more steps to reach the same accuracy as training offline, because you cannot optimize your loss function against your entire data set in each step.

However, the paper you linked uses online learning to intelligently select training examples a few a time in order to speed up convergence of the model. Their method attempts to select the examples that are currently hardest for the model, so that the model may make the most improvement at each training step.

Comment: How do they select the examples? They randomly pick 40 images/batch and for each image they calculate the embedding, then use each image as anchor paired with the hardest negative and all the other positives and feed the triplet to the network? Am I right?